# How to extract Ajax returned info in this particular code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in client side:

```
this.formValidation = function() {
        // Parse forms
        $('.submit.btn').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
        $.each($('form.validate'), function(){
            $(this).validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    var data = $(form).serializeArray();
                    var action = $(form).attr('action');
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: action,
                        data: data,
                        success: function(d) {
                            // Prepare the message
                            var message = '';
                            $.each(d, function(k, m){
                                var messageType = 'boolean' === $.type(m.status) ? (m.status?'success':'error') : m.status;
                                message += '<div class="alert alert-'+messageType+'">'+m.message+'</div>';
                            });
                            // Replace the form with the message
                            $(form).replaceWith($(message));
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            var error = $('<div class="alert alert-error">error </div>');
                            $(form).replaceWith(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

supported messagetypes are: 'success' and 'error' for the css to load the style

and this code in server:

```
     $d= array(
 'status' => 'success',
 'm.status'=> 'success',
 'message'=>'success'
 );
    echo json_encode($d);
?>
```

But it returns no success message. How should I form the array in server side?

I know it enters the success section of the code but I don't know how to write the variables in the server side.

The JavaScript code should not be changed, I just have to modify the server php.
How can I do this?

Also I have a few questions:

1. Should the variable name in server php be the same as the variable name inside the function? in this example when I echo $d should it be like  `success: function(d) {` or I can use other names as well? Are they even related?
2. When are the variables 'k' and 'm' in `function(k, m){` are coming from? can you explain what the function does?

Comment: as you said 'd' is the data that is returned from my phpfile (not in the code but it's called newsletter.php)
so if d is an array of variables and in 'function(k,m)' k is index and m is the value right ? so what's m.message and m.status ? 
how should i parse those two variables from my php script ?

Comment: what does this line do ? 
var messageType = 'boolean' === $.type(m.status) ? (m.status?'success':'error') : m.status;

Answer (score 0):

Start a `longest mile` (dunno if its called that, but it stuck with me) witch is where you do a `console.log('something');` from where you should see something and gradually moving backwards on the execution until you do see something, nice an easy way to isolate the problem.

Also if you are using `Google Chrome` the dev tools has a nice tab for network, you can see the ajax request and what it returned. Maybe it returned an error 500?

This way you can easily diagnose any ajax call.

As for your questions:

1. no, all the jQuery parameter does is name the variable for the results. So you can name it anything, I usually use `resp` personally.
2. the parameters in each refer to "key" and "value" (in this case its using m, just like above). read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for more info on that.

Comment: OK thanks for the question i understand most of the code now.
i used firefox firebug extension and the ajax returns the value so there's no network problem. i just don't know what to send to get the script properly working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

i had to use multidimention arrays to respond to json.

the correct code in server side is :

```
  $d=array(
    array(
    'status'=>'success',
    'message'=>'mail sent'
    ),
    array(
    'status'=>'info',
    'message'=>'thank you!'
    )

   );
 //Set JSON header
 //warning : UTF-8 byte order causes the Cannot modify header information error !!!!
  header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($d);
```